# How can all matching array items be removed from a collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a structure like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62e25c91dab0625cc8604198"),
    "sources" : [
        {
            "createDate" : ISODate("2022-07-25T17:16:12.407+02:00"),
            "type" : "name1"
        },
        {
            "createDate" : ISODate("2022-07-25T17:16:12.407+02:00"),
            "type" : "name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to remove all items with "type" : "name2".

This statement seems to find the item but does not remove it:

```
db.collection.update({} ,{  $pull: { "sources" : { $elemMatch: { "type":"name2"}}}})
```

Note I want to remove all matching items.

Comment: The [$pull docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) suggest that $elemMatch is not needed here (and indeed is counterproductive). [This playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XL2-lDTgmGB) seems to support that. Also note $elemMatch is generally not needed for a single condition (see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition)). Finally, $pull docs also state that it removes '_all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition_'

Comment: @user20042973 Thank you with updateMany this worked for me, could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [$pull docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) suggest that `$elemMatch` is not needed here (and indeed is counterproductive, emphasis added):

> The `$pull` operator treats each element as a top-level object. The query is applied to each element. The expression does not need to use `$elemMatch` to specify match conditions.
>
> On the contrary, the following operation **does not** `$pull` any elements from the original collection
>
> ```
> db.survey.updateMany(
>  { },
>  { $pull: { results: { $elemMatch: { score: 8 , item: "B" } } } }
> )
> ```

The top of that same docs page begins with the following (emphasis added again):

> The `$pull` operator removes from an existing array **all instances** of a value or values that match a specified condition.

The following command seems to work on your sample document:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $pull: {
    "sources": {
      "type": "name2"
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XL2-lDTgmGB).

Two related asides:

- `$elemMatch` is generally not needed when there is only a single query condition (see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition)).
- When using the older `update()` command/syntax (as opposed to the newer `updateOne()` and `updateMany()`) you may need to specify `multi: true` in the options as in the third argument in order to modify more than one document.